# How Do I Prevent Spring From Failing If Corda Isn't Started?

Tags: java, spring-boot, corda

If you connect to Corda with Spring Boot like in the [samples](https://github.com/corda/samples-java/blob/master/Advanced/secretsanta-cordapp/clients/src/main/java/net/corda/samples/secretsanta/webserver/NodeRPCConnection.java) the Spring Boot application will fail if the Corda node is not started - even when the bean is marked as `@Lazy`.

How do we keep the Spring application running and wait until Corda has fully initialised?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the use case where you'd want to do this, if you're going to run a webserver on a corda node it's so that you can use that webserver to trigger your flows over local RPC, but only interact from the outside world with the webserver.

Generally speaking, this is the most convenient way I'm aware of to use HTTP to trigger corda flows on a node. If you really want to ensure that it's a separate node just run the webserver separately from the corda node or create a node identity that doesn't do anything and have that node just exist to trigger flows on the network.

Comment: The use case is that Corda might not have been up yet or it might have gone down during the day. I don't want the rest api to go down when Corda does. I don't know what your 2nd paragraph is about.